# Как убрать ProgressDialog по завершении загрузки файлов?

Tags: android, progress-bar, download

В слушателе кнопки я запускаю поток, в котором произвожу загрузку файлов. После запуска потока текст кнопки меняется с "Загрузить" на "Читать". Я не сообразил, как сделать это после завершения потока/загрузки. Поэтому поставил на событие запуск ProgressDialog - чтобы пользователь некоторое время дождался завершения загрузки. Иначе он получает ошибку, так как файлов еще не загружено. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать ProgressDialog именно после завершения загрузки? Гружу сторонней библиотекой [Fetch](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch)

Вот код слушателя:

```
    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String fileListB = "list_" + "book_" + bookId + ".json";
                    String jsReadFile = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileListB);
                    Log.d(TAG, jsReadFile);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Book book = gson.fromJson(jsReadFile, Book.class);
                    List<String> pages = book.getPageUrl();
                    List<String> sounds = book.getSoundUrl();
                    String[] urlsPages = pages.toArray(new String[0]);
                    String[] urlsSounds = sounds.toArray(new String[0]);
                    String[] urlsFiles = ArrayAndArrayNewArray(urlsPages, urlsSounds);
                    DownloadFilesBook(urlsFiles);
                }
            });
            mThread.start(); // запустили поток 2
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BookCardActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progressDialogText));
            progressDialog.show();

            buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
            buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NextActivity();
                }
            });
        }
    });
} else {
    buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NextActivity();
        }
    });

}
```

Вот код метода загрузки файлов

```
private void downloadFilesBook(String[] urlsFiles) {
    mFetch = Fetch.newInstance(this);
    String folderB = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
    String fileNameForWrite = "book_" + bookId + ".json";


    File bookfolder = new File(String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(folderB)));
    ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < urlsFiles.length; i++) {
        String url = urlsFiles[i];
        String path = String.valueOf(bookfolder);
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        Log.d("my2", fileName);
        Request request = new Request(url, path, fileName);
        String pageFilePath = path + "/" + fileName;
        Log.d("my2", pageFilePath);
        pagesFiles.add(pageFilePath);
        downloadId = mFetch.enqueue(request);
    }

    BookFiles bookFiles = new BookFiles();
    bookFiles.setBookID(bookId);

    ArrayList<String> pagesPath = getPagesArray(pagesFiles);
    ArrayList<String> soundsPath = getSoundsArray(pagesFiles);

    bookFiles.setPagesPath(pagesPath);
    bookFiles.setSoundsPath(soundsPath);
    Gson gson11 = new Gson();
    String filesJson = gson11.toJson(bookFiles);

    MyJSON.saveData(getApplicationContext(), filesJson, fileNameForWrite);
}
```

Comment: метод dismiss() у диалога. а вообще показывать прогресс диалогом практика не очень

Comment: dismiss() его уберёт моментально, не дожидаясь завершения загрузки

Comment: ну так вызовите его после того как закончилась загрузка)

Comment: это классическая работа с потоками, вам никто не ответит на вопрос пока вы не покажите, что у вас делает  DownloadFilesBook(urlsFiles); и почему он с большой буквы ?  Это класс какой-то, типо Async? или это метод. Если он в отдельном потоке, ещё создает асинхронную задачу, то всё сложней, если он не плодит там внутри потоки, то немного проще

Comment: Да кстати ProgressDialog bad practice, от гугла и он в какой-то API уже deprecated, советуют юзать ProgressBar, ну это между делом

Comment: исправил название метода на downloadFilesBook, код метода добавил в вопрос

Comment: Sviat Volkov, я про это и спрашиваю... Слушателем бимблиотеки не могу поймать окончание загрузки, или неправильно его использую... Я новичок в программировании, проект у меня тренировочный, вот и задаю глупые вопросы

Answer (score 2):

Я никогда не работал с `fetch`, но если посмотреть документацию, то там есть методы для отслеживания процесса скачивания.

Для этого необходимо присвоить обработчик к `mFetch`

Пример

```
mFetch.addListener(new FetchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueued(@NotNull Download download) {
       ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(@NotNull Download download) {
       //здесь обработайте завершение загрузки (dismissу диалога, например)
    }

.....
```

[Документация](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch/blob/v2/README.md)

Comment: да, я смотрел документацию, но почему-то не подцепляет событие, или неправильно делаю...

Comment: @Вячеслав надо смотреть ваши попытки реализовать этот слушатель. Добавьте их в вопрос.

Comment: да это похоже на ответ, и скорей всего это делается в отдельном потоке, тогда автору не надо создавать Thread, а просто повесить listener.

Comment: к сожалению, пока писал свое приложение, сторонняя библотека обновилась... теперь нужно переделывать всю логику загрузки

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил использовать `AsyncTask` - это хорошая практика в `Android`. Перенести код из `Thread.run()` в `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` - метод выполняется в отдельном потоке. А в `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` убрать `ProgressDialog` - этот метод выполняется в ui-потоке. Отображение диалога можно перенести в `AsyncTask.onPreExecute()` - этот тоже в ui-потоке.

Comment: у меня в методе используется сторонняя библиотека (см. выше), которая наверняка использует потоки для загрузки очереди файлов, и здесь возможна накладка с использованием AsyncTask

Comment: я бы не сказал, что asyncTask это хорошая практика для сетевых операций